# Using integer variables in Subprocess.run

Tags: python, bash, command-line-arguments, pipeline

I am currently coding a pipeline in python with subprocess.run. I have loops to generate variables that I have to test. The structure of the code is something like `for variable in range(n): subprocess.run(["%s -d variable" %(something)], shell = True)`. But my results always show that the variable had reset to 1. What should I instead do such that the loop will work?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show what your output is.  You put ```variable``` as ```"variable"```  so all your runs are ```<something> -d variable```   Don't you mean ```"%s -d %d" % (something, variable)```?

Comment: Either your code example is wrong or you don't actually use the variable. Try `"%s -d %d" % (something, variable)`. Besides, you better avoid format strings here for security reasons and write `subprocess.run([something, "-d", variable])` instead.